# Empty list of generic arguments

Tags: f#

[Section 15.3 of the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#HighPrecedenceTypeApplication) mentions the sequence `< >` with intervening whitespace is an allowed form. It indicates an empty list of generic arguments, which allows for the following oddity.

```
type A() = class end
let a = new A< >()
```

Why is this allowed? Since generic types can be instantiated with type args omitted, is this a type checking optimization of sorts?

Comment: Can you think of a reason to specifically go and prohibit it?

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes. Type args aren't applicable to non-generic classes??

Comment: @Tomalak: It seems even weirder since type args must be explicit on classes. If that wasn't the case, I could see this being useful to indicate the class is not generic.

Comment: Tangentially, you *are* allowed to call `Type.GetGenericArguments` on a non-generic type - you get an empty array, rather than a throw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Ramon that it makes things more consistent, in that you can treat non-generic types as a degenerate case of types of generic arity 0.  In the case of types which are "overloaded" by generic arity, this allows you to be more explicit about which type you're referring to:

```
type T(o:obj) = class end
type T<'t>(t:'t) = class end

let t = T("test")
let t' = T< >("test")
let t'' = T<_>("test")
```

Without thinking carefully about overload resolution, it's not necessarily obvious what type `t` has, but it's completely clear what types `t'` and `t''` have.

Comment: Good example. I was struggling to come up with a use case.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is just for consistency. You can do `List<int>` and `Dictionary<string, bool>`, so you can also do `int< >`.

Comment: How is that consistent? `List` and `Dictionary` are generic, `int` is not.

Comment: You are looking at it at the wrong way (well, it is the right way, but the wrong way in order to understand how they thought). ``List`` has 1 generic argument, so it gets one item in the ``< >``, ``Dictionary`` has 2, so it gets two items and ``int`` has 0, so it gets zero items. Instead of thinking about it booleanily (a lovely adjective), is or isn't generic, think about it as "how many generic arguments it has".

Comment: To clarify: I don't think you should use that syntax, but it is there for this reason.